# Legitimacy of differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

We have a function $$f(t)= \int_{1}^{t} \int _{1}^{t} e^{xyt} dy \space dx $$ This can be differentiated by the chain rule, taking $h=e^{xyt}, g=h=\int_{1}^{t} x \space dx,$ and applying the chain rule to $f(g(h))$ but how do we know that the function is differentiable? For a function where $t$ is not also in the limit of the integral, it would be enough to show that the inner function is continuous but here I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of t as an arbitrary parameter. You are doing a double integral, with area elements $dy,dx$. Note that $e^{xy}$ is a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^2$, all continuous functions on a compact set are Riemann integerable. Note that we are integrating over the compact set $K=[1,t]\times [1,t]$, and so we can just carry out the double integral, (keep in mind that $x,t$ are constants when we do the inner integral). The rest is just plug & chug.

Also we know $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ is differentiable because it is clearly $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$